# Does the choice of a complex inner product affect Krylov methods?

Tags: linear-algebra, iterative-method, krylov-method, complex-arithmetic

As far as I understand there are two definitions of the complex inner product:
$$(a,b) = b^H a$$
and
$$(a,b) = a^H b$$
I know some linear algebra libraries such as BLAS and Eigen uses the second one.

However, I've seen some papers, such as [this one](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226884771_Complex_Conjugate_Gradient_methods), that use the first one.
I would like to know if using one instead of the other would dramatically affect the behavior of a Krylov method such as the CG or the BiCGSTAB.

Comment: As long as the orthogonal projection gets adapted so that it is linear also for complex coefficients, nothing should change.